# function called from .cpp file which is defined in in .c file

Tags: c++, c, linux

In projectA.vcproj

### fileA.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void functionA();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

### fileA.c

```
void functionA()
{
//function defined
}
```

In projectB.vcproj:

### fileB.h

```
void functionB() ;
```

### fileB.cpp

```
#include "fileA.h"
#include "fileB.h"
void functionB() {
    functionA(); // error: undefined reference to 'functionA'
}
```

I am getting the error when I compile my code on Linux, please help me fix this.

Comment: Did you forget to `#include fileA.h` from `fileB.cpp`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No, the error message for that is "error: ‘functionA’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Yes, I have included it. Sorry I forgot to mention it here. Thanks. I made an edit just now.

Comment: You should show the command line that is producing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link the files together.

```
Source code ---compile--> Object files ---link--> Application

fileA.c ------------+
                    |---> fileA.o ---------+
                +---+                      |
                |                          |
fileA.h --------+                          +--> a.out
                |                          |
                +---+                      |
                    |---> fileB.o ---------+
fileB.cpp ----------+
```

The "undefined reference to XXX" error message is given by the linker, after successful compilation.

You need to make sure all files are linked together.

```
$ ls
fileA.c  fileA.h  fileB.cpp  fileB.h
$ gcc -c fileA.c
$ g++ -c fileB.cpp
fileA.c  fileA.h  fileA.o  fileB.cpp  fileB.h  fileB.o
$ g++ fileA.o fileB.o
$ ls
a.out  fileA.c  fileA.h  fileA.o  fileB.cpp  fileB.h  fileB.o
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is probably coming from the linker, so you need to ensure you compile both source files and link them properly:

```
gcc -c fileA.c
g++ -c fileB.cpp
g++ -o program fileB.o fileA.o
```

You should, of course, ensure that `fileA.c` includes `fileA.h`.  If you omit the header from `fileA.c` and if you compile the code using:

```
g++ -c fileA.c                       # g++ instead of gcc
g++ -c fileB.cpp
g++ -o program fileB.o fileA.o
```

Then you will get the missing reference because `g++` will have created a C++ linkage `functionA()` but will be expecting to call a C linkage `functionA()`.

However, you should not compile C code with `g++`; that is asking for trouble.

---

When originally asked, `fileB.cpp` didn't include any headers.

#### fileB.cpp

```
#include "fileB.h"
#include "fileA.h"  // Provide extern "C" declaration of functionA()
void functionB() {
    functionA();
}
```

Comment: +1 Linking issue is certainly the problem, because the error message points to the linker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header file of functionA in functionB's header file. So in fileB.h add the line #include "fileA.h"

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile?

```
gcc filea.c fileb.cpp
```

Should do the Trick.

Comment: That probably won't work; `gcc` probably will reject the C++ source, and it doesn't address the source code level issues in the C++ code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It will compile the C++ source as C++ (GCC chooses language based on extension by default) but it won't link in the standard C++ library, which will probably cause link errors.